# Potential of a wire grounded through a resistor

Tags: voltage

I'm reading a paper that uses a simple setup to measure the zeta potential of liquid-air interfaces (that's not really important). Their method/apparatus is given in this picture
[image]

In the paper itself they write: *Initially, the detection electrode is exposed to air and thus has an electrical potential of V0 (relative to the earth). When the electrode contacts the electrolyte solution–air interface which has a zeta potential of xi, the difference of the electrical potentials of these two surfaces (one is the electrode–air surface, the other is the electrolyte solution–air interface) generates an electrical current through the measurement circuit.*

Here's my question - when the electrode is grounded like that through a resistor and it's in air (i.e. there's virtually no current), doesn't its potential equal the potential of earth?

Comment: There is also the matter that I can't spot any return path for the current so I don't even understand how any current is supposed to flow in the first place. Could be that I'm just missing something about the topic as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Virtually no current doesn't mean no current.

Comment: @JorenVaes Exactly! The only reason there would be a (transient) current through that resistor (which causes a voltage drop that's measured) is due to the potential difference between the liquid and ground. That's IMHO, I'm also not familiar with the topic.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on zeta potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_potential) may help. 'Fraid it didn't help _me_, though

Comment: @peterG The statement that bothers me does not have to do with zeta potential per se, but rather with general physics/electricity - is the wire at ground potential?

Comment: First thing is, in so far as if that diagram were an actual detailed schematic, you would be right. But, the diagram is intended to just sketch out in principle how it works. Also, zeta potential apparently is an electrostatic phenomenon, and different rules apply ( or more correctly, different approximations are made about the same rules) in the electrostatic domain. For example, an electrostatic field meter can be made using  a high-impedance amplifier connected single-endedly to a small metal plate. [I'm only submitting this hand-waving because no-one else has posted anything so far!]